# How to use LEAST / GREATER functions in QueryDSL?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm looking for use LEAST / GREATER functions in a QueryDSL fashion way (like in Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

My issue is to select the minimal distance between several given double expressions:

```
NumberExpression<Double> minimal = least(exp1, exp2, ..., expN);
query.select(minimal);
```

In the deep, my use case is to select the minimal distance between two spatial points:

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<>(this.entityManager);
NumberExpression<Double> distance = leastFunctionToFind(
                qEntity.point.distance(pointA),
                qEntity.point.distance(pointB)
        );
query.select(distance);
```

---

I think the `entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().least()` doesn't work for my use case because it takes only one parameter.

(`LEAST` not to be confused with the `MIN` operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-aggregate.html, used to aggregate rows)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my issue.

My QueryDSL use Hibernate v5.6 that doesn't support `LEAST` and `GREATEST` postgres functions for the moment.

To make it available, just create a `PostgresCustomDialect` that extends the default `PostgresDialect` as follow:

```
public class PostgresCustomDialect extends PostgisDialect {

    public PostgresCustomDialect() {
        super();

        registerFunction(
                "least",
                new StandardSQLFunction("least", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        );

        registerFunction(
                "greatest",
                new StandardSQLFunction("greatest", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        );
    }

}
```

And update your hibernate config to target your custom dialect :

```
hibernate:
        dialect: com.path.to.your.hibernate.PostgresCustomDialect
```

And now, your function is available on the queryDSL context !

Use it as follow:

```
NumberExpression<Double> distance = Expressions.numberTemplate(
   Double.class, "least({0})",
   Expressions.list(
      qEntity.point.distance(pointA),
      qEntity.point.distance(pointB)
   )
)

query.select(distance).from(qEntity);
-- select the shortest distance between (entityPoint-pointA) and (entityPoint-pointB)
```